# How to include a folder with resources in the build

Tags: next.js

I need some config text files to be included in the build, they are used at the server side and will be opened with readFileSync, these files are not loaded via import and don't have .js or .json extension so when doing a build they don't get included in the release, ¿ it's necessary to make a custom webpack config for this ?

These files should not be available from the internet, so i can't put them in the public folder.

i.e: in java normally you have a folder called src/main/resources folder for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `resources` (or any name, tbh) directory, put your files in there and use them from there on production. Building process in next.js is different than java, next.js will transpile your app into the `.next` directory and all your existing files will be available, too.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was trying to open the file relative to code location and didn't found it, as i was unable to find the file, thought that it wasn't being included in the distribution.

Folowing your advice i created the folder "resources" at root level, and then opened it relative to root folder (not starting with dot or slash) and worked fine, this is the code

fs.readFileSync(path.join("resources/certs/", file))

The final problem was that the file was a .pem file, a ca certificate, that was being ignored by .gitignore, so the build pipeline was letting it out.

Comment: hey @HansPoo this did not worked for me. I have created a dir under /app with some json files which later I am trying to read in api route handler. After running build I am not able to see new fir under .next :(